# web2py: SQLFORM URL duplicate validation

Tags: web2py

I want to forbid users being able to submit duplicate urls into the database.

Right now my approach is:

```
db.url.URL.requires=[IS_URL(error_message='URL Error'),
                     IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'url.URL',error_message='Dupilcated URL')]
```

It covers the case for with "http" and without "http". 
For example, if www.123.com is already in database, then user could not submit http://www.123.com.
But this approach does NOT cover the case with "https", i.e. the user still could submit https://www.123.com.

Is there anyway to prevent such duplication?

I think eliminating the "http"/"https" ,if any, in urls before calling SQLFORM().process(). In such way, the urls in database are all without "http"/"https". But I don't know how to edit user input before calling SQLFORM().process().

Right now my code is

```
url_form=SQLFORM(db.url).process()
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom validator to strip the http/https before further processing:

```
import re
db.url.URL.requires = [lambda url: (re.sub(r'http[s]?://', '', url), None),
                       IS_URL(error_message='URL Error'),
                       IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'url.URL',error_message='Dupilcated URL')]
```

Note, the custom validator returns a tuple including the altered URL and `None` (the `None` indicates that there is no error). That altered URL is then passed to the remaining two validators.

Note, by default, `IS_URL` will prepend "http://" to any URL that lacks a scheme (which will be all URLs in this case, since the first validator strips the scheme). To suppress that behavior, you can do `IS_URL(prepend_scheme=None)`.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I have seen lambda several times but I never actually understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [custom validator](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Custom-validators) that will check for both the http and https versions in the database. This also allows for formatting the URL. Think of all lowercase hostnames and removal of keyword arguments (`?a=b`) in the url. If you plan to do that, be sure to check out [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

The following code is untested, but may provide you with enough code to create your own solution.

```
class scheme_independant_url_is_not_in_db:
    def __init__(self, db,error_message='Duplicate URL'):
        self.db = db
        self.e = error_message

    def __call__(self, value):
        # test the entered uri
        url_validator = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db,'url.URL')
        value, error = url_validator(value)
        if error: 
            return value,self.e
        # find the opposing scheme
        if value.lower().startswith('http:'):
            opposite_scheme_value =  'https:'+value[5:] 
        elif value.lower().startswith('https:')
            opposite_scheme_value =  'http:'+value[6:] 
        # error on the opposite_scheme_value in db
        value, error = url_validator(opposite_scheme_value)
        if error: 
            return value,self.error_message
        # return the original url, preserving the original scheme
        return (value, None)
... 

db.url.URL.requires=[IS_URL(error_message='URL Error'),
                 scheme_independant_url_is_not_in_db(db)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Your code is very easy to understand.

Comment: An added benefit of not stripping the scheme might be that some websites offer different content or may be inaccessible.